# How to run a function in an angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

I have this Directive:

```
.directive('reorderDiv', function ($compile) {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        function shuffle(array) {
            var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

            // Elemente
            while (0 !== currentIndex) {

                // Die restlichen Elemente
                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                currentIndex -= 1;

                temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
                array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
                array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
            }

            return array;
        }
        elem.on('click', function () {

          console.log('called');
          var divs = angular.element(document.querySelector('.center'));
          console.log(divs);

          divs = shuffle(divs);
          var content = $compile(divs)(scope);
          elem.append(content);
        })
    }
})
```

My goal is, that if the view loads it should run the function `shuffle` and not on a click on the element. How can i do this?

I tried to use `elem.on("load")[...]` but this didn't work. Could somebody explain me, why this does not work?

Comment: Just call shuffle function after on `click` event..

Comment: hmm, that did not work. Also after a refresh..

Comment: Check this http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $onInit event to fire shuffle function when directive loads:

```
.directive('reorderDiv', function($compile) {
  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        // Elemente
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {

            // Die restlichen Elemente
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
  }
  var obj = {
    controller: function() {
      this.$onInit = function() {
        var divs = angular.element(document.querySelector('.center'));
        console.log(divs);

        shuffle(divs);
      }
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      elem.on('click', function() {

         console.log('called');

         var divs = angular.element(document.querySelector('.center'));
         console.log(divs);

         divs = shuffle(divs);
         var content = $compile(divs)(scope);
         elem.append(content);
      })
    }

  };
  return obj;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `shuffle` function with correct parameter inside directive. It will run.

Comment: That didn't work. I removed the on.click. Logs get called but the divs won't reorder.

Comment: have you called like `divs = shuffle(divs);` or `shuffle(divs);` ?

Comment: Like so: `divs = shuffle(divs);
          var content = $compile(divs)(scope);
          elem.append(content);` When i call it with `shuffle(divs);` also nothing happens. Is there a way to fire it when the view loads?